# Using set clipboard in vim?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, clipboard

I figured out two ways to make the clipboard more or less work but neither of them do exactly what I would like. What I want is a way to copy and paste to the clipboard but only when I explicitly tell vim to do so.

By default, I can paste from the system clipboard, using `"*p`, but I can't find a way to write to it without setting other options. If I `:set guioptions=a` then that will allow me to use `"+yf)` for example to yank text into the clipboard. However, I would prefer to use the same register for both reading and writing. As far as I can tell, the `*` register only reads and the `+` register only writes. (And it doesn't write unless I've set `guioptions=a`... which has the side-effect of automatically copying visually selected text, which isn't what I want.)

The solution that seems to come much closer to doing what I want it to do is

`:set clipboard=unnamedplus`

However, the problem with this is that now the unnamed register is my clipboard, so whenever I do `x` or `dd` I'm overriding my system clipboard. I can control this by setting and unsetting `clipboard` before and after I want to use it, but that can't be the best solution.

Is there a way that I can set the clipboard to be the equivalent of `unnamedplus` but for a named register instead? I've tried `set clipboard="*`, `:set clipboard="*+`, `:set clipboard="*plus`, `:set clipboard="0`, `"0plus`, and `"0+`, but all to  no avail. I've also tried omitting the `"` but that returned an error.

I'm using Vi IMproved 7.3 (Included patches 1-547; Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org;
Compiled by buildd@) My OS is Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several misconceptions about the clipboard registers. Read up `:help x11-selection` to understand the difference between `"*` and `"+`.

Basically, the `"*` register represents the current selection, e.g. when you mark a text (in the terminal) with the mouse. In addition, the `"+` register corresponds to the clipboard, i.e. what you usually access with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V. MS Windows only has the latter, on Linux / X11, these are two separate concepts. Maybe that got you confused. And yes, you can both read and write both from within Vim (provided Vim's clipboard support is functioning properly, which it should with the default Ubuntu packages).